# Why is wget failing on this image?

Tags: image, wget

I'm attempting to download an image from google books with wget (I've tried curl as well) and I continually get a 500 error

```
// COMMAND
wget "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=pztHgTT4BGUC&printsec=frontcover&img=1"
```

```
// OUTPUT
--2016-07-13 20:58:06--  http://books.google.com/books/content?id=pztHgTT4BGUC&printsec=frontcover&img=1
Resolving books.google.com... 216.58.194.206, 2607:f8b0:4005:801::200e
Connecting to books.google.com|216.58.194.206|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2016-07-13 20:58:06 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails for the same reason the URL will fail in a browser if you're not logged into Google:  The server refuses to serve you the content unless you're logged in.

You can probably copy a session cookie from an existing session if you log in with a browser and use it in wget.